# Symfony inject array through services.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject an array to Event Subscriber, but I also inject an other repository so I don't know how this will work:

Here's what I am trying:

services.yaml

```
Path\To\My\EventSubscriber\TerminateSubscriber:
    arguments:
        - { param1: 'myvalue', param2: 'myvalue2' }
```

TerminateSubscriber.php:

```
private Repository $repo;
/** @var array<string, string>  */
private array $config;

public function __construct(Repository $repo, array $config = [])
{
    $this->repo = $repo;
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

It says that the first parameter should be an instance of the Repo, array given.
But if I switch the parameters it says "optional parameter given before required"

EDIT

The array should look like this:

```
[
  "a" => [400],
  "b" => [400, 500],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close but you need some changes in your code. If you need to pass a Repository, array or string from service to class you need to pass it like this.

In service.yaml :

```
Path\To\My\EventSubscriber\TerminateSubscriber:
  arguments: [ App\Repository\MyRepository, [MyArray],"My String Value" ]
```

And in your construct:

```
/**
 * @param Repository $repo
 * @param array $config 
 * @param string $stringValue
 */
public function __construct(Repository $repo, array $config = [], string $stringValue)
{
    $this->repo = $repo;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->string = $string;
}
```

Comment: How do I define the array to look something like my edit post, check edit please

Comment: I don't think you will have any problem in that @Thomas Britsom. You can copy your code in the service where i have the `[MyArray]` . Try it and if have any error please post it back.

Comment: I don't know how to build that array in yaml

Comment: @ThomasBritsom [Expanded and Inlined Arrays](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#expanded-and-inlined-arrays)

Comment: by aligning fields with tabulators, you can create the array without the " [ " and  " ] " and naturally using newlines as you would expect it. and it does not look that ugly ( i mean, inline - inline is just ugly )